# nagios check_snmp reverse - CRITICAL=0 OK=1

Tags: nagios, check-snmp

I need to check the status of power supply units Cisco 7604 using Nagios. I decided to use the plugin check_snmp:

```
/usr/local/libexec/nagios/check_snmp -H 192.168.150.200 -o 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.91.1.1.1.1.4.13
SNMP OK - 1 | iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.91.1.1.1.1.4.13=1
```

wherein:

```
#show environment alarm threshold
environmental alarm thresholds:

power-supply 1 fan-fail: OK
  threshold #1 for power-supply 1 fan-fail:
    (sensor value != 0 ) is system minor alarm
```

How to set the CRITICAL for Nagios (CRITICAL=0, OK=1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with the [negate plugin.](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/negate)

(It's exactly what negate is for.)

Comment: I can not understand how to work with it:

`# /usr/local/libexec/nagios/check_snmp -H 192.168.150.200 -o 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.91.1.1.1.1.4.13 -c 1
SNMP OK - 1 | iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.91.1.1.1.1.4.13=1`

and

`# /usr/local/libexec/nagios/negate /usr/local/libexec/nagios/check_snmp -H 192.168.150.200 -o 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.91.1.1.1.1.4.13 -c 1
SNMP OK - 1 | iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.91.1.1.1.1.4.13=1`

Comment: Read the output of "negate --help". You probably want something like "negate -s -o CRITICAL -c OK" and then your usual plugin call.

Comment: The problem was a missing parameter "-s". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To check the power supply into the Cisco 7604 you can use the [plugin](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-Connections,-Stats-and-Bandwidth/check_switch_psu/details)

Answer (score 0):

Use -r 1 if value 1 is OK. Everything else is then critical.
"/usr/local/libexec/nagios/check_snmp -H 192.168.150.200 -o 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.91.1.1.1.1.4.13 -r 1"